# What is consciousness? Is it the ultimate reality of our universe? What implications do the various theories of consciousness have on human life?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, truth, reality, complexity

Does a child has more consciousness associated with her or her adult form?

What about her foetus? If her foetus is not yet properly developed (it has just accumulated a bit more mass and complexity than a single-celled zygote) then is it okay to halt its growth? Or are the questions are irrelevant because we have not yet developed a proper measure to quantify consciousness associated with a being or any object?

Consciousness means having subjective experience. Our brain not only takes in input with the help of different sensory organs (olifactory, visual, auditory etc.), processes it and then produces an output, which, besides updating our mental model of the reality, produces actions, speech and communication which are the means by which we impact the outer world.

If I hurt you, then you don't only process the stimulus and act accordingly to either hurt me or forgive me, but you would have that feeling and experience of being hurt by me. So the initial question, "Does a child has more consciousness associated with her or her adult form?", can now be put like, "Does a child have more subjective experience associated with her or her adult form?" This would lead most of us to conclude that her adult form has more subjective experience than her infant form.

So is the emergence of consciousness due to accumulation of more mass or components (panpsychism) and its association into a more complex structure (integrated information theory), or is it simply because of development of her brain into a more complex structure? The second point would mean that consciousness is the property of mind or information processors only, and there is some property or criteria which the information processors should have or satisfy which would lead to emergence of subjective experience (we don't ever think that current computers, the digital information processors have subjective experiences so there should be some property which the information processors should have to have subjective experience).

If the adult and infant form has same subjective experiences then we would have this law that with each living being associated is a concious being, then it should lead us to conclude that all organisms from prokaryotes to multicellular organisms like us are equivalent. This seems a less plausible description.

Vedanta philosophy has something to say in this regard. It says that Brahman (it is also called truth) permeates all the reality. It is the ultimate reality which forms the substratum of the universe. Each soul is its extension. So each soul is potentially divine. The impurities which are there within a human being are because of her mind (so what is mind? It cannot be part of truth because truth is pure; if it is again a part of Brahman then Brahman is not all pure which seems a more likely explanation). By seeking the truth, one uncovers the true potential and becomes divine.

I find it compelling to equate Brahman with consciousness.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ultimate reality of our universe?' - The universe exists billion years until humans with conscious mental processes developed. Why should these late arising processes have any universal impact? - Are you sure to know the meaning of Brahman? Atman - Brahman is a recurrent theme in the Upanishads, without a final solution about its meaning and about the relation of the two concepts.

Comment: Understanding what consciousness is, and what mind is, is one of the central questions of philosophy for the last 100 or so years.  If one applies Popperian falsification to the proposed answers, then there basically is consensus among philosophers that each of the proposed answers is falsified.  The ADVOCATES of an answer are not always convinced of this, but their peers think so.  You started your question with an empirical question -- is consciousness different in DEGREE among creatures. Intuitively, most of us think so.  Adults appear to be more conscious than infants. continued

Comment: And humans appear to be more conscious than insects.  BUT -- it is not clear that this is due to quantity of EXPERIECES, but more to their structured quality.  I suspect taht infants may have MORE experiences than adults -- but they are often inchoate.  And an insect may be MORE sensorily outfitted than a human, I don't know.  I don't think ANYONE knows the quantity of conscious experience vs unconscious processing for other species.  We DO know insects will have less unconscious processing.  So -- as critiques of this question: continued

Comment: 1) it is too broad for a phil SE question.  An answer would have to account for most philosophic thought from the last century of philosophy.  2) The assumption of consciousness degree == quantity of experiences does not seem to capture what most of us think of when we consider "degree of consciousness" and "quantity of experience" is unknowable for others, so there is no data to work from even if it were a valid metric.  3) You then leap to your own answer, and do not do your own self-criticism before doing so.  You should not expect your answer to work out, based on a century of failure.

Comment: I am not convinced that the word "divine" actually means anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at a foetus or zygote as their potential, then every female fertile cycle not resulting in conception is a crime, and every wasted sperm. Nature has included high levels of waste, and humans have other priorities than procreation and nurturing of infants. There is [evidence female reproductive autonomy has substantial positive social effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legalized_abortion_and_crime_effect), and the demographic transition from high numbers of children and high infant deaths, to low numbers of children and high investment in them, [can be linked to solving the biggest challenges the world faces](https://youtu.be/SR3jNfW2xHw).

Research links the increasing subjective speed of time as we age, to [fewer novel experiences that trigger learning](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/think-well/202011/why-time-goes-faster-we-age#:%7E:text=Children%20perceive%20and%20lay%20down,more%20rapidly%20as%20we%20age.). So you could argue that a child has *more subjectivity*, is typically more alive to and aware of the possibilities of each moment. We can use that insight, with framings like a Growth Mindset, or the need for Ongoing Professional Development, to see learning change and challenge, as crucial to maintaining cognitive functions. Working memory decreases with age, but cognitive challenges and active adaptation can allow us to work with that.

In Buddhist thought there is a fundamental universality to minds. They are each a 'mani', a jewel, at a junction of [Indra's Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net). I would relate this to intersubjectivity, and how reality should be understood as the composite of experiences of minds reflected in each other, not as separable from subjectivities (only generalised, by finding what is shared). This is a version of the Private Language Argument, communication intrinsically as arising from interaction.

[Integrated Information Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory) aims to find a quantifiable relationship between levels of awareness like waking sleep & anaesthesia, and the amount of information an organism can dynamically integrate. It would also allow comparison between life stages, individual humans, and between species. However in practice, it has led to very little progress, and though promising conceptually it is currently pretty much entirely speculative.

A more complex mind structure, like say more memory (eg augmented digitally), is obviously not *necessarily* (or even probably) linked to greater awareness or novel problem solving. [Fluid vs crystallised intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence) is a good way of picturing this. Because crystallised intelligence deals with increasingly familiar/revisited domains, it can be off-loaded to technology, calculators, databases, etc (I like the example of the [mental abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_abacus)). Fluid intelligence peaks at around age 20, and is linked to working memory capacity.

I would look to conscious self awareness as relating to the cognitive [Global Workspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_workspace_theory), and the specialisation of our brain hemispheres, one towards self-model, one towards world-model. That is non-conscious routines are maintaining an updated picture of the self, & the world, which appear as 'givens' in conscious awareness, which relates to working memory. When we get totally absorbed in activities, we drop the processing involved in maintaining the distinction between self & world. In the Global Workspace picture, working memory is for solving novel problems, and considering the self-model & updating it, eg forming intentions, is just one type of problem, one that is particularly useful socially (see the Dunbar Number indication of the origin of our neocortex in understanding intentions, not eg tool use). Substantial brain architecture generates the self, for social reasons, but awareness in the present moment can be more fully engaged, more working memory freed up, by dropping the processing of self-other.

I like the OrchOR picture of mind. I interpret the microtubules as related to fluid intelligence, their patterns of wiring together as crystallised intelligence. We can see minds as  rooted in this capacity to be present, and respond to presented problems in their own terms, founded in the mictotubules (eg the surprising power of even simple [connectomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectome)).

Which can be related to the Buddhist picture that at the level of direct presence in the moment, we are all participating in the same awareness, we are all in a sense deeply interchangeable, or mutually arising, each reflecting the whole universe like the jewels in Indra's Net.

I see this as more versatile than Brahman, because that involves not subjectivity but identity as fundamental. In the Indra's Net perspective, self is only a phenomena, a tool, to be picked up and put down, with no deep persistence. And we can see that we can all be deepened, by the way we reflect each other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is divine, as you conclude, but there are a couple of other pieces to consider.

You begin asking about consciousness, which you have defined as subjective experience. You equate this at the end to Brahman, which you have defined as a universal or absolute truth. I think the issue you have hit is that, while the two can be related, they cannot be the same. This is because the consciousness you began with was subjective, while the truth you end with is objective. They certainly can relate, but they cannot be the same.

My answer comes from a Christian background rather than Vedanta. Scripture defines both a soul and a spirit. The soul is similar to what you call consciousness (or a mind), in that it is the internal part of us that has subjective experience. The spirit is an animating force and is also a part of God. This is similar to your Brahman, which is both divine and yet a part of individuals. The two are then related (our spirits are all part of one God) but can be individually polluted (as we are all disconnected from God).

The answers to your questions then are:

- Consciousness is the internal part of an individual (as opposed to the external body) and is the filter for subjective experiences.
- The ultimate reality of our universe is God, who alone exists eternally and animates the rest of us.
- The implications of various theories would be too numerous to list, but in broad terms I would say that our understanding of consciousness is essentially our understanding of individuals. If we believe consciousness is divine, then people are divine and must be treated as such. If consciousness is an illusion, then we have no reason to treat individuals or the world at large as though it has any meaning. Lastly, if consciousness is an evolutionary trait, then it has no meaning beyond helping to ensure our survival. Under this assumption we can ascribe no rights to any individual purely because they have a conscious.